# Is it possible to make calculations in a Quake 3/Live hud?

Tags: 2d, gui

I would like to add a new field to a Quake 3/Quake Live HUD that shows the following number:

```
min(health + armour, health * 3) * (1.5 if guard_rune else 1)
```

This is the amount of damage you can take before getting killed, btw.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I know, it's not. People have tried this without success.